# How to ensure Port is open

Tags: tcp

How do I check if a port is opened in windows. And can it be seen what is accessing it or what has accessed it over the last while?

Comment: TO CHECK ON WINDOWS7 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall